# After the first phone() why doesn't the it work?

Tags: python

```
print("what type of device do you have phone, tablet or laptop(put brackets at      the end of your answer)?")

answer = input ("press enter and type in your answer. phone(), tablet() or            console()")

def phone():
    import webbrowser
    print("Do you have an iphone or samsung?")
    answer = input ('iphone/samsung:')
    if answer == "iphone":
    print("what type of iphone?")
    answer = input ('5, 6 or 7:')
    if answer == "samsung":
    print("what type of samsung do you have?")

    answer = input ('s5, s6 or s7:')
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation and ask the question in the *body* of the post.

Comment: In Python, the indentation is important. Your code is not indented correctly. Simply paste it into stackoverflow, select it and mark it as code with `Ctrl`+`K`

Comment: Also, questions seeking *debugging* (why isn't this code working), need to be asked as a [mcve]. We can't see how you called `phone()`

Comment: Why "press enter and type in your answer. phone(), tablet() or console()"? You aren't going to call `eval()` or `exec()` on unsanitized user input, are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent block, be more careful!

```
def phone():
    import webbrowser
    print("Do you have an iphone or samsung?")
    answer = input ('iphone/samsung:')
    if answer == "iphone":
        print("what type of iphone?")
        answer = input ('5, 6 or 7:')
    if answer == "samsung":
        print("what type of samsung do you have?")
        answer = input ('s5, s6 or s7:')
x = input("press enter and type in your answer. phone(), tablet() or console() ")
if x == 'phone()':
    phone()
elif x == 'tablet()':
    tablet()
elif x == 'console()':
    console()
```

Comment: This still doesn't really answer the question, which was why doesn't `input("press enter and type in your answer. phone(), tablet() or console()")"` work?

Comment: Edited, is this what he's looking for?

Comment: I think so, yes

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, what you have is this...

```
def foo():
    print("stuff")

answer = input("type foo()")
```

And `answer == "foo()"` is `True`.

You never called `foo()`, though, you just typed it in as a string.

You need to run it.

```
exec(answer)
```

**But**, `exec` is really bad, so instead, you should instead use `if` and `elif`'s to call the corresponding function.

```
if answer == 'foo()': 
    foo()
```